# Tracking changes in SQL Server on a BCP Imported Table

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I upload an Excel file using BCP. (Truncate the current table in DB every day and BCP in from the excel file to repopulate table).  It is important for me to keep a log of all the changes made to the rows (could be row additions or changes in columns of current rows).  The idea is to keep a log of all the changes made.

I have read a few articles online, where we can create a log table and trigger (have no idea how to do it). A table of logs that has columns like

```
Date | Field | Old Value | New Value.
```

Firstly, how to do this?

Secondly, whats a smarter way to not log truncating of table and just the actual changes. I'm thinking of creating a temp table (tbl_Excefile_Temp) where I will import the file and then UPDATE the current table (tbl_Excefile) from the tbl_Excefile_Temp This way all the changes made in the current table will get logged automatically in the logs table.

I know its a big use case, could you please guide.

Comment: Does your data have a key? How wide is the data? You may well be better off with an upsert method, rather than truncating and reinserting, as then you can easily determine what has changed in a logging process. Once you `TRUNCATE` the data, you have no idea what it looked like before and so any ability to audit the new data against the old is lost.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didnt even know that there was something called UPSERT. Exactly my point, that when I truncate table, I have no record of previous data. Its ideally a Employees Excel sheet. (Emp ID is Unique). So would be good to have a tracking mechanism of changes made on it . It has some 15 Columns, and may be 400 odd rows, obviously they keep changing..

Comment: I would suggest having a look at `MERGE` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL server 2016 or higher I would advise you to look into temporal tables. If you stop truncating and use a merge statement you have a very easy way of keeping a log. Whenever you make a change SQL server will write to old values away and add the datetimes when the old row was valid.

With temporal tables you can query your table as they were at a specific datetime. In regular use there is no difference with a non-temporal table.